# add thousand separation for ngModel in angular 5?

Tags: html, angular

I have a question in angular 5, in my project there are some inputs with text type
that their values are number like price. I want when user type number in input the if the number is more than thousand the separator will be visible. and also I don't want to use currency, just numbers more than three digits, get seperator just when user is typing. How can I do this? This is my html code:

```
<input  pattern="[0-9]+" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="property.rent" 
name="rent" type="text" required>
```

Thank you very much in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Use a directive.

```
import {Directive, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[forceDigits]'
})

export class InputNumber {

    public regexStr = '^[0-9]*$';

    @HostListener('keydown') onKeyDown() {
        let e = <KeyboardEvent> event;
        //conditions here
    }
}
```

Then add it to your html

```
<input  pattern="[0-9]+" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="property.rent" name="rent" type="text" required forceDigits>
```

Comment: You also need to add your directive to your app.module.ts.
I've just gave you a solution, not the exact implementation. Now you need it to figured out and algorithm to parse the input into the desired format

Comment: what should I write in onKeyDown function to reach my purpose